# Change picaso to AsyncTask

Tags: android

I am trying to use `AsyncTask` but I don't know how. Can you help me to change my adapter to picaso library to `AsyncTask`?

```
package com.beamreveriestudio.www.bootcamp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;



public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public ListAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d)
    {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

    {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listdata, null);

        TextView judul = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.judul);
        TextView alamat = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.alamat);
        ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.gambar);

        HashMap<String, String> daftar = new HashMap<String, String>();
        daftar = data.get(position);

        alamat.setText(daftar.get(Daftarwisata.TAG_ALAMAT));
        judul.setText(daftar.get(Daftarwisata.TAG_NAMA));

        Picasso.with(activity.getApplicationContext())
                .load(daftar.get(Daftarwisata.TAG_GAMBAR))
                .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(thumb_image);

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/loading-image-asynchronously-in-android-listview

Comment: import com.example.customizedlist.R; how can i fixed it ?

Comment: don't copy paste the code just like that. You need to change to `import com.beamreveriestudio.www.bootcamp.R`. Understand the code before copy pasting.